# Detect mobile phone by seeing if viewport is respected

Tags: mobile, width, meta-tags, viewport, detect

Hi sorry if this is already asked.  But I looked around quite a bit.

The methods I have found for detecting if a web user is using a mobile phone don't seem very nice.  They are: look at the user agent string (hackish), look for a narrow width (but what's narrow?).

Is there a direct way to see if the browser supports the `<meta viewport...>` directive?
I think that would be the best way.
Because that's what we want...  If the browser supports viewport (i.e. is mobile) use it.  Otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
http://detectmobilebrowser.com/

The meta viewport is seems to be implemented differently from the CSS attributes, so any solution involving reading the viewport width before specifying it may not be portable.

Comment: Thanks, gave you an upvote.  I see if that finds "Android" in the user agent string then it calls it a mobile browser.  But what about Android tablets?  I think a tablet users should see the regular view of a website.  Maybe there is no nice solution to this problem.